# Capturing index of an array onclick with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array, indexof, wordsearch

https://jsbin.com/zesegigego/edit?html,js,output

I'm creating a word search puzzle and at the point where I want to implement functionality to allow the users to mark the words they find. I have an array of s which contain randomly generated letters and letters to the words to be found. The s of the words to be found have a class="answerLetter", but I am having trouble capturing each index at a time to tell my JavaScript to change do something with those specific indexes I click on. I apologize if there is lack of clarity, but the jsbin link is above to view what I have so far.

I know how to do this with AngularJs where an ng-repeat can be "track by $index" and I just bring that specific index from the HTML to my controller by inserting the $index in the parenthesis of the function like so ng-click="selectThisIndex($index)". How do I do this with vanilla JavaScript?

https://jsbin.com/zesegigego/edit?html,js,output

```
//==============SUBMITTING ANSWERS=======================================

function showSubmit() {
document.getElementById('submitBut').innerHTML = 
'<button onclick="submitLetters()">SUBMIT LETTERS</button>';
var arrayOfTds = document.getElementsByClassName('answerLetter');
console.log(arrayOfTds);
}

//==============CREATING GRID OF RANDOM LETTERS====================

var cols = 20; 
var rows = 10; 
var html = ""; 

for(var i = 0; i <= rows; i++) { 
html += '<tr>'; 
for(var h= 0; h <= cols; h++) { 
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ'; 
    var random = parseInt(Math.random()*characters.length);
    var letter = characters.charAt(random); //returning random letter
    html += '<td onclick="showSubmit()">' + letter + '</td>'; 
} 
html += '</tr>'; 
}

document.getElementById('wsBox').innerHTML += html;
```

Comment: Please paste the relevant code directly into the question and format it as code.  External code references have a habit of disappearing or changing over time which then renders this question less than useful as a resource which goes against the rules here.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited my answer above and pasted the relevant code. I have not changed the jsbin, so if you'd like to see the other code it's in the link

Comment: Access your letters as **window.event.target** to access or modify theirs class. Other option is to pass **this** to **showSubmit** function and  access them in **showSubmit** function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .box {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      margin: 5px;
      float: right;
      background: #eee;
      border: solid 1px #ccc;
      list-style: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <ul></ul>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <script>
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      $("ul").append("<li class=\"box\">" + i + "</li>");
    }

    $(".box").each(function(index) {
      $(this).click(function() {
        console.log(index);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that worked, thanks :) is it much longer to do this in just JavaScript? Just curious.